# Passing bash variable as a pattern to awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to know how to pass a `bash variable` as a `pattern` to `awk`.
I have read several Q/As which tend to answer the same question, however, none of them solved my problem (probably, I am missing something!).

I have several files like this:

```
1   9909    23121  
1   23121   561510  
3   75879819    75902940  
3   75902940    75916152  
4   75916152    75982212  
3   75982212    75998727  
22  82964754    83232297 
X   59962662    60745473
```

and I want to create different files each containing same starting pattern and I only want to extract column 2 e.g. a file containing column 2 of all the rows starting with one, the other file containing column 2 of the rows starting with X etc.

My code looks like this:

```
for x in *.CNVs; do  
   for y in `seq 22` X Y; do  
        awk '/^$y/ {print $2}' $x > freec_${x}_${y}_st.txt;  
   done;  
done;
```

I have also tried using `-v` option like this:

```
for x in *.CNVs; do  
    for y in `seq 22` X Y; do  
        awk -v pattern="{$y}" '/^pattern/ {print $2}' $x > freec_${x}_${y}_st.txt;  
    done;  
done;
```

I don't get any error, all the files are created; however, they are all empty! Any suggestion is much appreciated!

[**Edit**]
I found a neater way using `grep` (before, I was thinking that it cannot be done by `grep`!):

```
for x in *.CNVs; do
    for y in `seq 22` X Y; do
        grep "^${y}\s" $x | cut -f2 > ${x}_${y}_st.txt;
    done;
done;
```

Using `grep` is helpful since by using `\s`, I can discriminate between line starting with 2, 21 and 22 etc.

Comment: Don't use the word `pattern` as it's very ambiguous. You seem to be talking about a regular expression so just say `regexp` or similar.

Comment: Maybe also `abstain` from using `code` formatting for `terms` which are not `code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded in regexp literals (`/.../`). You need to use the `~` operator and string literals.

```
awk -v pattern="$y" '$0 ~ "^"pattern {print $2}' "$x" > "freec_${x}_${y}_st.txt"
```

You also need to be careful with any pattern metacharacters/etc. in the pattern.